# Change the Amazon Storage Gateway behind an existing File Share

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-storage-gateway

I have a File share which is already available but I created a new Gateway with a new EC2 instance. I would like to ask if there is a possibility to keep the File Share but just change the Storage Gateway it points to?